# Eclipse Luna GDB debugger support

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-luna

I'm having some issue with gdb on my mac running 10.8.5. Specifically the GDB install is not code signed and must be ran as root. This has become problematic and limits my ability to utilize GDB from with in eclipse luna. I have tried 99% of the options available to code sign GDB with a certificate to no success.

What can I do to get GDB to work in Eclipse luna and display variables and data structures?

[image]

With the gdb-apple debugger I get the following error when stepping in to code. FAILED to execute MI command.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `gdb` as Eclipse won't work with the `lldb` debugger that comes with `clang++`. Right now I guess you have only an alias for `gdb` pointing to the `lldb` debugger, so you need to install the proper GNU `gdb`. 
Easiest way is via `macports`,

```
sudo port install gdb
```

then codesign the `/opt/local/bin/ggdb` (note the name, `ggdb` not `gdb`). Here is a link which explains how to codesign it (skip the installation part, go to Certifying GDB)

http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

PS: the method in the link is applicable to older versions of OS X, not just Mavericks.

Comment: I have done that process successfully (gdb-apple) however the version installed is GNU gdb 6.3.50.20050815-cvs. How can I get a more current version. I would like to get close to the Tenth Edition, for gdb version 7.9.50.20150211-cvs.  no I actually have gdb 7.8 installed but it requires root. Tried code signing with no success

Comment: @d_blk just try `sudo port install gdb`, then codesign it. The name of the debugger will be `ggdb`

Comment: I final got this to work. My gdb was signed with a signature that was no longer on the machine. I uninstalled gdb, then re-install and signed with a new cert.